# How to safely add a new directory to the PATH from a windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Usage of setx.exe would be allowed but the final solution must be able to be called several times without creating duplicate entries. If you call setx, it will create duplicates.

Usage of other scripting is not allowed but another free utility could be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I regularly use my `ADDPATH.BAT` batch file, it updates the `PATH` environment variable after checking if it already contains the new folder, to prevent duplicates.

```
@echo off
if .%1==. goto help
echo %PATH% | find /C /I "%*" >nul
if errorlevel 1 ( 
set path=%path%;%*
) 
:help
echo %PATH%
```

It might be useful for you as a model. Adapt it to your requirements, replacing `%*` to your desired folder and changing `SET` to `SETX` for permanent changes.